# AWS CloudFormation Template - How to start

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to write a template for AWS CloudFormation and don't know how to start. I manage 2 different domains on AWS and would like to use single CNF template to create Windows servers for both domains.

In example, first question in the template should ask you to choose domain for "Domain" parameter:

1. "abc.com" or
2. "123.com"

Second question in template for "WSUSGroup" parameter should offer you different list options based on previous answer. I would like to choose different WSUS groups based on domain I have selected. In example:

- If I choose "abc.com" for "Domain" parameter, than list should offer:

  1. WSUS-ABC-US
  2. WSUS-ABC-EU
- And if I choose "123.com" for "Domain", list should offer:

  1. 123-US
  2. 123-APAC

Is this doable at all? I would like to split many option based on domain selection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, Cloudformation uses JSON/YAML formatting for the templates. There is some "logic" you can put into a template and the difficulty is anything from Easy to Hard to Nope, can't do that. What you are asking for MIGHT be able to be done. I can think of a couple ways that it MIGHT work, but what you are asking for is for someone to do the work for you. That is why you are getting downvotes. I would look at the documentation, learn YAML or JASON (I suggest YAML for beginners) and at least TRY before you ask here. Search for some samples and go from there too. I will try if I have time.

Comment: I did a little looking, but I am not sure if I will have time to work through this today, but I woulds start here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html

Comment: You are right. I am sorry. I will try to post more detailed question, with my tryouts later on. Thanks again.

Comment: It's okay, everyone needs time to learn. I'm still chewing on this, but I hope the link I send helped some. I will try and make time to help on this later.

Answer (score 0):

You have two specific questions, I'll try to answer those.

First, CF supports [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

If you want user to choose the domain from a limited list of options, you can use `AllowedValues`. Something along the lines:

```
  Domain:
    Type: String
    Default: abc.com
    AllowedValues:
      - abc.com
      - 123.com
```

Second, you seem to want to make choices for another parameter depending on the first parameter.

I do not think this is directly possible.

However, there might be some workarounds available.

For instance, if values for `WSUSGroup` are so to speak "parallelled" for different domains (i.e. `123-US` corresponds to `WSUS-ABC-US` and `123-APAC` corresponds to `WSUS-ABC-EU`), you might use [`FindInMap`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html) to select actual `WSUSGroup` values depending on the value of `Domain`. This might look as follows.

Let's define a parameter `WSUSGroupKey` with abstract values `US` and `EU` corresponding to specific values `WSUS-ABC-US`/`WSUS-ABC-EU` or `123-US`/`123-APAC`:

```
  WSUSGroupKey:
    Type: String
    Default: US
    AllowedValues:
      - US
      - EU
```

Then we define a `Domain` + `WSUSGroupKey` to `WSUSGroup` mapping:

```
Mappings:
  WSUSGroupMapping:
    abc.com:
      US: 'WSUS-ABC-US'
      EU: 'WSUS-ABC-EU'
    123.com:
      US: '123-US'
      EU: '123-APAC'
```

Having done that, we can now look up `WSUSGroup` values based on `Domain` and `WSUSGroupKey` parameters using `FindInMap`:

```
      SomeProperty: !FindInMap
        - WSUSGroupMapping
        - !Ref 'Domain'
        - !Ref 'WSUSGroupKey'
```